Vitest, beforeEach and concurrent
I am writing some tests in vitest and I wonder if something like this is safe:
describe.concurrent("Let's do some testing:", 
  () => {
    let ctx;

    beforeEach(async 
      () => {
          ctx = createContext();
      }
    );

    test("Test", 
      async () => {
          ctx.doSomething()
      }
    );

    {....}
    
  }
);

My intuition tells me it's not but maybe vitest does something underhood and can't find any information on this.
